# Network indicator disappeared in Lubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, lubuntu

I just upgraded to Lubuntu 14.04 from 13.10 successufully, via `do-release-upgrade`.

But after reboot, I found that the network indicator has been disappeared, so I cannot switch different network connection as before in 13.10 or 12.04, and cannot use VPN by clicking.

I tried:

- add item with name containing 'network' for indicator bar right below
- open item in menu with name containing 'network'

But none of these is the network indicator (switcher) that we use in 13.10.

Does 14.04 change to another network indicator?

Is there alternative indicator for this, or any `command` for network switch.

Comment: Do restarting made it appear?

Comment: Try to run `nm-applet` from a terminal (not sure if Lubuntu uses Network Manager...). Did you get the indicator or any error/output?

Comment: hi @Braiam, it still disappears after reboot.

Comment: hi @Salem, I'll try this later.

Comment: @Scotv http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html

Comment: hi @Salem, great, It works now.

Comment: None of solutions worked for me. To fix that I follow the solution on "https://stefanoprenna.com/blog/2014/05/04/support-fix-missing-network-icon-in-lubuntu-14-04-nm-applet/" and add one more step --> Exec=dbus-launch nm-applet

Comment: Just a footnote: `nm-applet &` for the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right click on panel, choose "Add remove panel item", then at tab "Panel Applets" press "Add" button, then choose "Manage networks".
Now at the panel you'll have two network icons, one for cable and one for wireless connections

If you prefer the traditional Network applet, open Lxterminal and just type the word: nm-applet

Now at the panel you'll have the traditional "up and down arrows" indicating the Network Manager to make changes.
Notice that when you close the Lxterminal, the icon will dissapeasr again.

Have luck

Comment: Hi @a friend. I did add 'Manage networks' like this before, but this would bring me 2 or 3 icons in applet bar. nm-applet is better.  And from **Salem** comment, this will be better.  Thanks. [solution here](http://webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html)

Comment: there is no manage network

Comment: This doesn't work in Gnome-Shell.