# Broadcom B43 WiFi not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop.

Under the networking menu at the top, it is not showing any WiFi options.

How can I get Wifi working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

I have a Broadcom BCM4311 WLAN card.

Comment: Please edit your question with the kind of wireless card you have: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/55868/114818). If it doesn't work, [edit] with detailed explanation of what happened in your case, also incorporate all the information that was asked in earlier comments.

Comment: Problem solved until reboot, and go back after reboot, here result for 'iwconfig' command line: `wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:off/any Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=19 dBm Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off Power Management:off`

Comment: Just Suspend the system and then resume back in. This surprisingly solves the wifi issue! Worked for me [ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 on Asus laptop]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Broadcom BCM4311,

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms

sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

See here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA(Wireless)

Comment: That worked like a charm :)

Comment: My son's laptop finally worked with this.

Comment: When the WiFi stopped working for some reason reinstalling the b43 packages did the trick for me: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer`.

Comment: didn't work for me... bcm4311 on 14.04, still cant connect to wifi network

Comment: it showing me **firmware-b43-installer is already the newest version.** but still not showing WiFi option. I'm using 14.04 version. ANy suggestion?

Comment: wordked in ubuntu 14.04.03 in pavilion dm1 br version, thanks

Comment: I have BCM4360 on Ubuntu 14.04 and `firmware-b43-installer` stopped me from even being able to connect to ethernet. I needed to remove it (via synaptic package manager) to connect to ethernet again. Install with care!

Answer (score 2):

you can go to

> settings> Software and updates > additional drivers

you can get most of wireless/Graphics drivers. You can install any 3rd party driver software you require. Hope that helps!

Comment: this helped. open source driver was choosen, but this only works with proprietary. after choosing proprietary driver in this dialog, wifi worked again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Broadcom (BCM43xx) wireless network card like me, [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx) might help.

I connected the laptop using a cable and ran:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

to install the driver and then rebooted.

(It would be helpful to add your network card to the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you faced a problem like me [Network indicator disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449709/network-indicator-disappeared-in-lubuntu/449798?noredirect=1#449798).

A solution that works for me is here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html

Simply speaking, try `nm-applet` at first, if you take back WiFi indicator, then add `nm-applet` to Default applications for LXSession.

Comment: @scoze the link is broken

Comment: @AbdulHameed  sorry, I fixed the link, try again