# Broadcom B4311 Drivers Installed and Non-Functional

Tags: wireless, 14.04, broadcom, b43

Just did a clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 on an HP laptop with a Broadcom 4311 wireless card.  I've installed the following packages in an attempt to find the driver for it.

b43-fwcutter
firmware-b43-installer
linux-firmware-nonfree

The wireless card worked fine in Ubuntu 13.10, but in Ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't even show up in the network manager, and toggling the hardware switch doesn't do anything.  I installed "sysinfo" and it properly identifies the wireless card model, but for some reason installing the driver doesn't seem to have gotten it to work.

I've done some searching for various wireless tutorials, but most of them seem to pertain to helping people find a driver.  I've got the driver, it's the same one I used in the previous version of Ubuntu, it just isn't working any more, :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcom B43 WiFi not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450631/broadcom-b43-wifi-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer on this site and got my card working.  I had installed the correct driver, but apparently 14.04 had by default installed the bcmwl and broadcom-sta stuff which was overriding the b43 packages I had installed.

The answer can be found at: [Broadcom B43 WiFi not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450631/wifi-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: The best things come from within!  ;)