# Wifi not working, upgrade to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, network-manager, connection

I've upgraded my system with ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 and then my wifi adapter Broadcom BCM43142 [14e4:4365] is not working and the wireless connection is not even showing up in the list.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/453430/270959

Comment: I had a mysterious wifi problem on 14.04: [See this answer on AskUbuntu][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/607244/396480

Answer (score 0):

I've been through same problem..... do not worry, the adapter works fine...

follow the link..

https://github.com/akrasic/broadcom-wl

download the zip and follow the README....

**Some points to remember:**

1. make sure when patching Makefile... there will be a prompt to you "File to patch", just write "Makefile" there and press enter key...(this is just a slight glitch)
2. The readme assumes you did not install any other drivers and doing installation on fresh installation. If you have installed any other drivers for testing for bcm43142, please remove it or blacklist them otherwise the broadcom-wl not going to work....
3. Do not forget to do a "depmod -a" at last as it will make mapping for device to modprobe module wl.ko

Comment: I just updated the complete software packages and then it just works fine. Thank you.