# WiFi not working on Asus U32 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, asus

I know this problem has been stated before, but none of the solution worked for me. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Asus U32 laptop, alongside Windows 8. Recently I've updated from 12.04 to 14.04 and the wifi can't be enable now. Before upgrading, it worked perfectly. I have no hardware button to switch it on/off, so it must be software related. On windows 8 the wifi is working ok.

I've tried Fn+F2 to enable it, but it also goes on for about 1 second. Also, I've tried the rfkill unblock command in terminal, but nothing.

I don't know what else should I try.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/453430/270959

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: @harshjv I've tried installing the driver but the problem hasn't been solved.

Comment: @WildMan here's what I got: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7485501/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please copy and paste this command:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

Reboot and wifi should work.

you may have to toggle your fn keys to remove the hard block after rebooting.

Here is the link with full details courtesy of varun and chili555.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558

Answer (score 0):

I faced smiler problem with my asus laptop.
Just download driver from below link and install 
It work for me Ubuntu 14.10 asus lapi

https://github.com/tobiasBora/MT7630E_3.16/archive/master.zip

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, could you please explain in a little more detail what this driver does and how to compile it for the sake of clarity?