# Wifi not working with Asus X551 and Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I just bought an Asus X551 and installed ubuntu but the wireless connections can't seem to work. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Could it be in Airplane mode (fn F2 toggles on/off)?

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch" and following links have solved it for me

[WiFi not working on Asus U32 with Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468620/wifi-not-working-on-asus-u32-with-ubuntu-14-04)

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1680490

- As root, create a file named e.g. asus-wifi.conf and put it in in /etc/modprobe.d/
- Insert this line in it: options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1
- Reboot and see if wifi works.

I had same problem using Fedora F19, F20 and Ubuntu F14.04