# Backports wifi driver wont reload after eboot on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, laptop, asus

I am having some problems with wifi after installing Ubuntu on my ASUS F551CA.After having problems with a hard block (which i solved by black listing one of the two drivers) I was able to get a connection but it would only discover signals and log on after I suspended the system. I attempted to solve this by using Ndiswrapper and and the relevant windows drive, which failed. After uninstalling the driver wifi no longer at all. I installed backports 3.13.2-1 using the instructions I found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/240616/can-you-install-atheros-ath9k-driver-from-3-2-kernel-into-3-5-kernel

Wifi switched on immediately but when I rebooted there was no detection or logon again. I did the same again with backports 3.15.1-1. Once again it worked but stopped working on reboot. Can anyone offer some advice?

PS: I also tried a few other instructions posted here without success such as : [WiFi not working on Asus U32 with Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468620/wifi-not-working-on-asus-u32-with-ubuntu-14-04/468847#468847)

Comment: BTW the Network Adapter is AR9485

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you recompile backports:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.15.1-1   <--or wherever you extracted the package
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe ath9k
echo ath9k | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it.