# Compaq 6510b can't connect to wireless network on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: wireless, broadcom, hp

I have been trying to connect to my wireless network for weeks, tried a bunch of new and legacy open source and Broadcom STA-proprietary drivers for BCM4311 (103c:1371, wl) without the option to connect in the menu, "blue" led-indicator not working at all and I'm not able to connect.

I've been trying to connect for weeks, tried all of the suggested solutions, all in vain:
[Broadcom B43 WiFi not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450631/broadcom-b43-wifi-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (32-bits) with all the latest updates installed (Linux 3.13.0-44-generic)

If I were to install Windows 7 it would work flawlessly, but I rather not walk down that road again, it's one of the main reasons I chose Ubuntu 14.04 over Windows 8 and their stupid "modern"-UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please obtain a temporary internet connection and open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working as expected.

If the wireless switch is not working, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp-wmi
rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Any improvement? If so, we will blacklist the module.

Please see this bug report about the same laptop and the same problem: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/183548

> Thanks Erin,the reset to default bios settings worked for me too!

Comment: I tried that, but it's still the same, unable to connect, grayed out in all menus (can't turn it on) and no blue led-indicator. I rather not be forced to revert back to Windows 7 unless there isn't anything more I can do about it that might help?

Comment: May we please see the diagnostic as described here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: I ran your script and saved my report http://pastebin.com/XbjVDTvM

Comment: Your wireless shows as "Hard blocked: yes," suggesting that you should find and switch the hardware wireless switch or key combination. It may be #18 here: http://www.server-unit.ru/tekhopisaniya/files/12684_OV.gif

Comment: I've tried to enable the wireless network adapter numerous times before without effect http://youtu.be/cSg3Q5r9Ecw that's the "blue led-indicator" i was referring to earlier and here's another picture from within Ubuntu https://i.imgur.com/UNdQfO3.jpg this happens whenever I try to active the adapter (from within) it jumps back and remains being grayed out.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: That did unfortunately not solve my problem, it says "soft blocked: no" and "hard blocked: yes".

Comment: Which did not solve your problem? Removing the hp-wmi module or resetting your BIOS to defaults? Or both?

Comment: I tried fiddling with the "lan/wlan switching" and power saving options in the bios earlier, with no effect, restarted my computer once more to double check, enter the bios menu (only this time I chose to "restore defaults") logged into Ubuntu, blue-led wifi-indicator starts flashing, wireless network tab isn't grayed out as before and I'm able to successfully pick my wireless network and connect! Thank you so much for all of your hard work and support!