# do i need to download separate driver for wifi?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, hp

do i need to download separate driver for wifi?

Comment: if your wifi is not working, then yes!

Comment: @DavidCole Yes , there can be many  possibilities! what i meant is you dont need to look for drivers if your wifi is working properly. And maybe, he is running internet on lan .

Answer (score 2):

Usually not, most of the drivers are included with Ubuntu.

Comment: actually my wifi isn't working the option is disabled can u help

Comment: Which laptop model do you have?

Comment: compaq notebook series 15 S004

Comment: Please see this question: http://askubuntu.com/a/453430/138369