# No (easy) networking after upgrade to Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, upgrade, 20.04, xubuntu, lts

After taking the option to upgrade to Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS I no longer have any networking capability.

E.g. Output of `ping www.Google.com` :

```
ping: www.Google.com: Name or service unknown
```

Output of `ping 192.168.0.1` (my network router):

```
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

Result of wireless-info script: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xQzTjkBZ6t/

At first I thought this was "just a Wi-Fi issue", so I tried tethering, and I am now using a cat 5 cable to my router, with the same result.

Following some stfw, I can manually bring up my Ethernet interface, after each boot with:

```
sudo ip link set dev enp6s0 down
sudo dhclient enp6s0
```

Something more permanent (and something that will get WiFi working) would be nice though!

Any ideas please?

Comment: There are quite a few things that may have gone wrong. Let's try to gather all of the diagnostics in just one report. Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Can you ping an IP address instead of hostname and if yes what is in your /etc/resolv.conf file?

Comment: @chili555 done!

Comment: @SimpliFixed no: "Network is unreachable" (added to question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your wireless script, we see:

> NetworkManager is not installed (package "network-manager").

Using the connected ethernet, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager
```

Reboot. Clicking the Network Manager icon at the top right should now permit you to connect easily with wireless or ethernet.

Comment: OK - wired Ethernet now works (thank you!).  There is no network manager icon though.  I tried to run the script again, and now it gives: `44: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: Please remove the old copy of the *script* (not wireless-info) and download a new copy and try again. Does the icon appear if you do: `sudo nm-applet &` ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help!

Yes, the applet appears if I execute it manually, only for the current session though.

I'm going to modify my session settings file to 'persist' the applet.  It seems weird to me that the network-manager modules managed appear to have become 'left out' of my installation during the upgrade, I have no idea how that has happened!

I will try to refresh+run the script again later on (I'm away from the PC in question for a few hours now)

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/449709/network-indicator-disappeared-in-lubuntu

Comment: Started up my PC again.  Applet now appears. Script now runs without showing any issues.  No idea what the 'fixes' could have been (beyond applying a power cycle, rather than a reboot)