# No easy networking in Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, ubuntu-studio

After my previous networking woes got fixed ([No (easy) networking after upgrade to Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280063/no-easy-networking-after-upgrade-to-xubuntu-20-04-1-lts)) I have swapped over to Ubuntu Studio.  The 22.04.01 LTS release recommends a clean install, which I have done, and... you guessed it I now need to do `sudo ip link set dev wlp7s0 down && dhclient wlp7s0` after every boot to get a fully working connection (without doing this some sites such as Google, are accessible, others, such as AskUbuntu(!) are not).

Results of wireless info script are linked below (split into two parts).

Part 1: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ks7wdfjwbF/

Part 2: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TtvJ8q56wZ/

I've spotted that `lsmod` output points out that the driver that's been installed for me is related to the rtl8192ce, so I don't know if that is my issue, and I'm not sure how to 'force' the correct driver to be used.  [In the past I've used the RTL8188CE drivers published by FreedomBen on GitHub but they are presently not compiling: https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/issues/157 ]

Edit: Additional Info results: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DjmnRDfjvN/

Edit 2:

```
$ sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Comment: "so let me know how to share the rest and I will" Please give us the link to a second, and, if needed, third paste. Thanks.

Comment: @Chili555 Done!

Comment: [Seems as though it's actually a clipboard problem, and the string `''` breaks the copy/paste somehow]

Comment: that is the correct driver, so not the issue.

Comment: "without doing this some sites such as Google, are accessible, others, such as AskUbuntu(!) are not" This makes me wonder if you are not getting a proper (or any) DNS nameservers from the access point/router. Please set fixed DNS in Network Manager: https://www.ricmedia.com/images/117.webp and reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: Fixed DNS gives no improvement, I still need to `sudo ip link set dev wlp7s0 down && dhclient wlp7s0`.  I've run the script before doing this, and have linked the result from my post above.  (I don't seem to have an IPv4 address allocated?)

Comment: Indeed. No IPv4 address. May we see: `sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` Do all other devices; i.e. phones, tablets, etc. work properly on this network?

Comment: @chili555 I've added the result to my OP.  Everything else on the network seems to be fine (this PC was too, until I ran the clean install!)

Comment: [In case it's relevant, the results are the same before and after `sudo ip link...`]

Comment: While there quite obviously is something wrong, I regret that after studying your readings carefully, I see nothing fixable. Sorry. Perhaps another wireless specialist will come by and correct me.

Comment: I've had a search around for Ubuntu IPv4 issues (for clues) and it seems I'm not alone. Unfortunately most of the threads end with someone saying, "well, if it was a real problem there would be hundreds of people complaining". :-(

Comment: @chili555 it seems there may be some weirdness inside NetworkManager's DHCP client, after forcing it to use `dhclient` instead I have IPv4 on every boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging around, I noticed that there were some people questioning the built-in DHCP client of NetworkManager, and [after reading the docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html), I have added:

```
dhcp=dhclient
```

To the `[main]` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Since doing this everything has been working just fine.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for adding the solution. The searchers will appreciate it.